# How to properly use self.assertRaisesRegex as a context manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

Please check the below code:

```
import unittest


def fn():
    raise KeyError('my message')


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_passes(self):
        with self.assertRaisesRegex(KeyError, 'my message'):
            fn()

        with self.assertRaisesRegex(KeyError, 'my'):
            fn()

    def test_fails(self):
        # Why does this test fail?
        # Isn't '^my message$' a valid regex?
        # How do I check if the message is exactly 'my message'?
        with self.assertRaisesRegex(KeyError, '^my message$'):
            fn()


unittest.main()
```

In the output, I get the below message for the test `test_fails`:

> AssertionError: "^my message$" does not match "'my message'"

---

**What am I missing?**

---

As mentioned in the comments, these are my questions:

- Why does this test fail?
- Isn't `'^my message$'` a valid regex?
- How do I check if the message is `exactly 'my message'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the `AssertionError` carefully, you will see that the `assertRaisesRegex` method is actually trying to match your pattern against `'my message'`, including the quotes.

This is because, [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaisesRegex), the method is pattern matching against the string representation of the raised exception, which you can see by performing the string conversion yourself:

```
>>> str(KeyError('my message'))
"'my message'"
```

By fixing the start and end points of the match in your regular expression, you are therefore causing this assertion to fail. The first two cases work as expected as they are unaffected by the presence of quote marks in the string representation.